# A generalized form of Young's inequality $\prod_{i} {a_{i}}^{p_{i}} \leq \sum_{i} p_{i} a_{i}$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove this form of Young's inequality, which I found on its Wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#/Generalizations). To get the original Young's inequality $a b \leq \frac{a^{p}}{p}+\frac{b^{q}}{q}$ with $a,b\ge0$ and $p,q>0$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$, we let $a_1=a^p, a_2=b^q, p_1=1/p,p_2=1/q$. Could you confirm is my proof is fine?

---

If $a_1, \ldots, a_n \ge 0$ and $p_1,\ldots,p_n \ge0$ such that $\sum p_i = 1$, then $$\prod_{i} {a_{i}}^{p_{i}} \leq \sum_{i} p_{i} a_{i}.$$

---

**Proof:**

WLOG, we assume that the LHS is strictly positive and that $a_i>0$ for all $i$. Because the function $\ln$ is strictly increasing, the inequality is equivalent to $$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \ln a_i \le \ln \left (\sum_{i=1}^n p_{i} a_{i} \right ).$$

We proceed by induction on $n$. The case $n=2$ holds thanks to the convexity of $\ln$. Assume it hods for all $k \le n-1$. We aim to prove it for $k =n$. In fact, \begin{align}
\ln \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} a_{i} \right ) &= \ln \left [ \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \right ) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{p_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} p_j } a_{i} + p_{n} a_{n} \right ] \\
&\underset{\le}{(1)}  \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \right ) \ln \left [  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{p_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} p_j } a_{i} \right ] + p_{n} \ln a_{n} \\
&\underset{\le}{(2)} \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \right )  \left [  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{p_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} p_j} \ln a_{i} \right ] + p_{n} \ln a_{n} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \ln a_i.
\end{align}

Here we apply inductive hypothesis with $k=2$ in (1) and $k=n-1$ in $(2)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks reasonable (except the inequality signs are written the wrong way around in $(1)$ and $(2)$, they should be $\ge$). Note that in your induction proof, you are effectively just proving Jensen's Inequality for finitely many points. (You could replace $\log$ with a general concave function and your proof would hold.)